# For a partition $\mathcal{D}$, $\forall A\in \sigma(\mathcal{D}), A = \bigcup_{k \in \mathcal{N}} D_k$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let be $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ a measure space and $\mathcal{D}= \{D_1, D_2, D_3,... \}$, a enumerable colection of disjoint subsets of $\Omega$, a partition of $\Omega$, that is, $\Omega = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}D_i$. Let be $\sigma(\mathcal{D})$ the sigma algebra generated by $\mathcal{D}$. Remember that $\sigma(\mathcal{D}) = \bigcap_{\mathcal{D}\subset\mathcal{A}},\mathcal{A}$, where $\mathcal{A}$ is any $\sigma$- algebra. With this definition, I would like verificate the following:
$$\forall A\in \sigma(\mathcal{D}), A = \bigcup_{k \in \mathcal{N}} D_k$$

whith $N \subseteq \mathbb{N}$.

Is it true? I can do something as the following:

$$A\subseteq \Omega \Rightarrow A = \bigcup_{k \in \mathcal{N}} D_k \cap A.$$ 
but nothing more that this. Some others tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If you show $\mathcal{A_*}:=\{\bigcup_{k \in \mathcal{N}} D_k : \mathcal{N} \subseteq \mathbb{N}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{D}$, then $\sigma(\mathcal{D}) \subseteq \mathcal{A}_*$.
The other direction $\mathcal{A}_* \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{D})$ is easy to show.